# Chemistry or Mathematics

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that I have two mixtures, V and W. I make a solution A by mixing V and W in a 2:5 ratio. I make another solution B by mixing V and W in a 3:4 ratio. I then make one more solution C by mixing A and B in a 1:6 ratio. What is the ratio of solution V to solution W in solution C?

Answer (score 0):

(I will assume the first mix is x and the second mix is y).

So, solution c consists of two parts, one with x and one with y.

The one with x makes up one seventh of the whole solution, and in it two sevenths are v. So $1/7 \cdot 2/7 = 2/49$ are v.

Now, for the next part (with y), it makes up six sevenths of the whole solution, and in it three sevenths are v. So $6/7 \cdot 3/7 = ...$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Ok sorry, so it would be 18/49 + 2/49 = 20/49?

Comment: @mathjunkie That's right! :) And so the rest is W.

Comment: So V = 20/49 and W = 29/49

Comment: And since the question asks what is the ratio of solution V to solution W, it would be 20:29. Right? @naslundx

Comment: @math101 Yep, there you go!

Answer (score 0):

$$C=\frac{1(\frac{2}{5})}{6(\frac{3}{4})}$$